# React increment counter when scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to run a function every time I scroll to the bottom and increment a counter, but the counter should only go up to 4, everything after that should be ignored. My current attempt looks like this

```
const [ fCount, setFCount ] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight && fCount < 5) {
     setFCount(fc => fc + 1);
     console.log(fCount)
    }
  })
}, []);
```

However it doesn't work, it just logs the initial value (1) as many times as I scroll to the bottom. And if I add the **fCount** value to the dependency array, then it logs

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
```

Just so we're clear, the counter is extended by another part of the app, it's not just for the lolz. How can I get a normal counter that logs 1-2-3-4 when you scroll enough times to the bottom?

Comment: `fCount` inside `useEffect` is stale, because the closure is not updated when it changes (empty dependencies array - `[]`). Move the console.log to the body of the function, and you'll see it change on each render.

Comment: You're right, now it changes from number to number, but now the less-than-five constraint doesn't work, when I scroll to the bottom it just increments as many times as I scrolled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your code is referencing the `fCount` closure variable. The value of that is locked in when the effect ran, so it will always be 1. When you set the state though, you're doing it right: `setFCount(fc => fc + 1);`. That function gets passed the latest value of the state.

The fix is to move all the code that needs the latest value into that function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    setCount(fc => {
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight && fc < 5) {
        console.log(fc + 1);
        return fc + 1;
      } else {
        return fc;
      }
    });
  })
}, []);
```

P.S, don't forget to clean up your effect and tear down the event listener:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const onScroll = () => {
    setCount(fc => {
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight && fc < 5) {
        console.log(fc + 1);
        return fc + 1;
      } else {
        return fc;
      }
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }
}
```

Comment: The number increments in a better fashion, but the ` fc < 5 ` constraint does not seem to work this way, the number increases indefinitely

Comment: So I forgot to re-add the fCount as a dependency, with that in place, now both the limit and the code work, thanks!